# What's the difference between CASE and IF in mysql

Tags: mysql

I found very strange MySQL behavior:

I have a string with umlaut letters, and I run some IF expression on it.
Something like:

```
IF(length(field) < 10, '', replace(field, "\n", "<BR>"))
```

It it works fine.

However, if I replace this if by CASE, then the result is cut on the first unlaut letter!

```
CASE WHEN length(field)<10 THEN '' ELSE replace(field, "\n", "<BR>") END
```

Also, I noticed that it happens only when there is also GROUP BY part in the query.

I can't understand what's the difference between CASE and IF - from logical point of view both should return the same result exactly.

Anyone knows why the is difference between these two commands?

Comment: What does "the result is cut on the first unlaut letter" mean?  What's an "unlaut letter"?  What version of MySQL are you using?  If you mean to check if field has 10 *characters* (as opposed to 10 bytes) you should use [CHAR_LENGTH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length) instead of LENGTH.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

"IF is a single fork, "CASE" can be multiple
Use "Case" if you have more than two values optional values, "IF" when you have only two values.

**General structure of CASE is:**

```
CASE x
WHEN a THEN ..
WHEN b THEN ..
...
ELSE
END
```

**General structure of IF:**

```
IF (expr)
THEN...
ELSE...
END
```

So, basically IF is a CASE with only one 'WHEN' statement.

Comment: Right, but what I'm asking is why there could be a difference between the result of IF and the result of one statement CASE?

Comment: The difference is pretty basic.  The IF statement is useful if you’re trying to evaluate something to a TRUE/FALSE condition.  The CASE statement is used when you have multiple possible conditions.  You could accomplish the same thing with nested IF statements, but that gets messy.