# MySQL CONCAT multiple fields with IF statement

Tags: mysql, if-statement, concatenation

I'm trying to do something I thought would be simple, but I'm stuck. I basically want to create a single address field from multiple address part fields, using an IF statement to use either an address or intersection. Here is my statement to make the field:

```
        CONCAT(loc_name,'\n',
            IF ( add_number != '' && add_street != '' ) THEN 
                CONCAT(add_number,' ',add_street,'\n')
            ELSEIF ( x_street_1 != '' && x_street_2 != '' ) THEN 
                CONCAT(x_street_1,' &amp; ',x_street_2,'\n')
            END IF
        ,city,', ', 
            IF ( state != '') THEN 
                CONCAT(state,' ',country,'\n')
            ELSEIF ( x_street_1 != '' && x_street_2 != '' ) THEN 
                CONCAT(country,'\n')
            END IF
        ) AS loc_info
```

But it doesn't like what I am doing at all, it throws an error at:

```
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') THEN \n\t\t\t\t\t\tadd_number,' ',add_street,'\n'\n\t\t\t\t\tELSEIF ( x_street_1 != '' && x_"
```

Which seems like it doesn't like my empty field ('') notation. But I don't know why. Can I not use the IF statement inside a CONCAT like that?

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax is not correct. You want to use `CASE`:

```
SET @loc_name = 'Location';
SET @add_street = 'Add Street';
SET @add_number = '10';
SET @x_street_1 = 'Street 1';
SET @x_street_2 = 'Street 2';
SET @city = 'City';
SET @state = 'State';
SET @country = 'Country';

SELECT Concat(@loc_name, '\n', CASE 
                                 WHEN @add_number != '' 
                                      AND @add_street != '' THEN 
                                 Concat(@add_number, ' ', @add_street, '\n') 
                                 WHEN @x_street_1 != '' 
                                      AND @x_street_2 != '' THEN 
                                 Concat(@x_street_1, ' &amp; ', @x_street_2, 
                                 '\n') 
                               end, @city, ', ', CASE 
                                                   WHEN @state != '' THEN 
       Concat(@state, ' ', @country, '\n') 
              WHEN ( @x_street_1 != '' 
                     AND @x_street_2 != '' ) THEN Concat(@country, '\n') 
                                                 end) AS loc_info
```

**Result**

```
|                                    LOC_INFO |
-----------------------------------------------
| Location
10 Add Street
City, State Country
 |
```

Just find and replace `@` with .

Comment: Cool, and I found this quick explanation on the difference between CASE and IF: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699908/whats-the-difference-between-case-and-if-in-mysql

Answer (score 13):

IIRC, the syntax you want to use is

```
IF(condition, expression_if_true, expression_if_false)
```

I could be wrong, but you might want to try that.

Answer (score 2):

this might also help:

```
CONCAT(loc_name,'\n',
            IF ( add_number != '' && add_street != '' , 
                CONCAT(add_number,' ',add_street,'\n'),
                IF ( x_street_1 != '' && x_street_2 != '' , 
                   CONCAT(x_street_1,' &amp; ',x_street_2,'\n'),""
                   )
               ),

        city,
         ',' , 
            IF ( state != '',
                CONCAT(state,' ',country,'\n'),
                IF ( x_street_1 != '' && x_street_2 != '' , 
                   CONCAT(country,'\n'),""
                   )
               ) AS loc_info
```

also what are you comparing here `state != ''` is it against null values?? 
 if so **this will give you incorrect answer** you have to use `state IS NOT NULL` instead of that.

Comment: That's good to know about the null. But I believe the are all empty, non-null fields.